# SmartFace show sliderdrawer

Tags: smartface.io

I trying to learn SmartFace App Development Platform. I added a SliderDrawer in Page then after I added codes as follows. But this codes not working in OnShow() event. How can I do this? Maybe I can do with write a lot of code. But I want to do without writing a lot of code.

```js
function Page1_Self_OnShow() {

  Pages.Page1.SliderDrawer1.show();


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue for Android, it will be fixed.But you can solve the problem until the bug is fixed as follows:

```
function Page1_Self_OnShow() {
    var timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
            setHello();
        }, 200);

    function setHello() {
        Pages.Page1.SliderDrawer1.show();
    }
    function cancelHello() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get it now. Thank you very much.